# How to deserialize different object representations to a POJO?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

On the client I have a Javascript application operating on entities and some of them are referenced with wrapper object, which contains a unique key of an instance on server-side - basically some sort of reference. Some are handled as-is, with all entity fields present.

When I send entity with modifications to persist it on the server, some fields which are themselves entities are references, and some are full objects.

For example, say I have a Car, CarModel and Garage, the incoming JSON can look like this:

```
{
    addedItems: [{
        "@class": "mydoamin.Car",
        belongsTo: {
            "key": "Unique_Garage_Key"
        },
        carModel: {
            name: "New Car Model",
            wheelSize: 14,
            doors: 5
        }
    },{
        "@class": "mydomain.Car",
        belongsTo: {
            "name": "New Garage"
        },
        carModel: {
            key: "Unique_Key_Of_Existing_Car_Model"
        }
    }]
}
```

For this to work on server part, I need a flexible deserializer, which can deserialize both formats into corresponding domain POJOs.

From what I've got from Jackson docs, I started a deserializer, but I'm out of clues how to write it correctly. What I've got in the deserializer is JsonParser and DeserializationContext. And I think it would be possible to achieve by parsing the stream twice, first as a wrapper object, and if that fails, try read it as domain object. 
Unfortunately i can't see that this is possible with JsonParser.

So basically my approach to deserializer is:

```
Car car;
try { 
    Wrapper carRef = jp.readValueAs(Wrapper.class);
    car = wrapper.unwrap(carRef);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // rewind the stream somehow...
    car = jp.readValueAs(Car.class);
}
```

Can somebody comment if that is possible with JsonParser and maybe better ideas on how to accomplish this deserialization case?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

TreeTraversingParser solved the problem.

```
        JsonNode rootEntityNode = jp.readValueAsTree();
        TreeTraversingParser treeTraversingParser = new TreeTraversingParser(rootEntityNode, jp.getCodec());
```

After this you can analyse parsed JsonNode for type and deserialize with correct one.